# How to recover host-manager in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I un-deployed the host-manager by accident. Can I just copy a host manager folder into tomcat?

Comment: What happens if you try it? That's a more interesting question than such a rhetorical question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is just some jsp and a few resources. Paste it in webapps/host-manager and restart your tomcat.

I did it and it works.

HIH